# JPA Desktop APP and Remote MySQL - How To

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a swing desktop app, with JPA and MySQL on the same machine. Now i want to take this same application to a network environment with the MySQL on a separate machine.

My options where to user either the ip-address or the machine-name for the host in my `persistence.xml`. But from your experience what is the best i can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host name is better, as they are more human friendly and less subject to change.

IP is more low level id of machine.

Regards
Philippe

Comment: Ok. Thanks on that. Now, can i expose the persistence.xml so that when the server changes it can be edited.

Comment: The good thing would rather be to choose a name that will never change, and to change the DNS entries when you migrate the database from one machine to another.